# Asp.Net Core Creating Database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using .net core technology and i am getting some error when i want to create new database.

This is my NorthwindContext class, i am writing server location here.

```
public class NorthwindContext : DbContext
    {

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa; Password=xxxxxxxx");
        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

And I want to create database with Console Project

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NorthwindContext context = new NorthwindContext();
            Product product1 = new Product() {ProductId = 1, CategoryId = 1, ProductName = "Asus Notebook", UnitPrice = 5000, UnitsInStock = 100};
            context.Products.Add(product1);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var products = context.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductName);
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(product.ProductName);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the result I am getting these:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll.

Additional information: Login failed for user 'sa'."

I am waiting your helps, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Error message contains enough information indeed.

> "login failed for user 'sa'"

Use connectionsting with trustedconnection instead of username&password.

It looks like:

```
connectionString="Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```